# Cant start animation from different class to another

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, graphics2d, repaint

I'm making a trackbar for a music application  I'm making. Basically Its a Rectangle2D that moves Horizontaly in a JPanel extended class 'TrackBar', the ActionListener is in another class 'TrackBarAction' and it is moved by a Timer inside the 'TrackBar' class and this time is started on 'Toolbar' class which is where the PLay and Pause button are.

- The problem I'm having is that it does not move. I added debug prints to console to see if it was reading the code and it is, except it does not repaint() for some reason, so it does read the code but does not repaint().

Here is the simplified code:

```
public class Toolbar extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public static boolean IS_PLAYING = false;

public Toolbar(){

      (...)

          pauseicon =  new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Icons/Pause.png"));    
          playicon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Icons/Play.png"));
          play = new JToggleButton(new ImageIcon(playicon.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)), false);            
        play.setOpaque(false);
        play.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        play.setBorderPainted(false);
        play.addItemListener ( new ItemListener( ) {

                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                    if(play.isSelected()){
                        play.setIcon((Icon)new ImageIcon(pauseicon.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
                        IS_PLAYING = true;
                        MainFrame.tb.t.start();     // THIS is where timer is called
                    } else {
                        play.setIcon((Icon)new ImageIcon(playicon.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
                        IS_PLAYING = false;
                        MainFrame.tb.t.stop();
                    }
                }});


        (...)

 } // end of constructor

} // end of class
```

The next class is the Trackbar class:

```
public class TrackBar extends JPanel{

private TrackBarAction tba = new TrackBarAction(this);
public static int TIME = 8;

public Timer t = new Timer(TIME, tba);
public static double x = 0, y = 0, velX = 0.5, velY = 0;


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    System.out.println("1"); // debug

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            //g2d.drawRect((int)x, (int)y, 10, 800);

            Rectangle2D r2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 10.0, 800.0);  // x,x, w, h
            g2d.setPaint(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g2d.fill(r2d);
            g2d.draw(r2d);

            System.out.println("2"); // debug
}

}
```

The next class is TrackBarAction which has the action listener:

```
public class TrackBarAction implements ActionListener{

private TrackBar tb;

public TrackBarAction(TrackBar tb){

    this.tb = tb;
}

 @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     System.out.println("3");

    // When it gets to the end, return to start point
        if(tb.x == 1024){
            tb.x = 0;
            tb.y = 0;
        }

        tb.x += tb.velX;
        tb.y += tb.velY;
        tb.repaint();
        System.out.println("4");
}

}
```

This is the main frame:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

public static ColourToolbar colourBar;

public static TrackBar tb;

public MainFrame(){

    super("VIPE by Prestige WorldWide");

    // Top colour toolbar for tones
    colourBar = new ColourToolbar();
    this.getContentPane().add(colourBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // The center where the drawing is done
    ImagePanel bg = new ImagePanel();   
        bg.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.setSize(1024,800); //w, h
        bg.setPreferredSize(size);
    this.getContentPane().add(bg, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    tb = new TrackBar();
    bg.add(tb, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //DrawBoard dboard =  new DrawBoard();
     //bg.add(dboard, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Image bgimage = (new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Icons/background.jpg"))).getImage();
    //JPanel bg = new JPanelWithBackground(bgimage);
    //this.getContentPane().add(bg, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    // The control toolbar where the settings and control buttons are.
    Toolbar toolBar = new Toolbar();
    this.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();

    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setSize(1024,768);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    //frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: I don't think `TrackBarAction` should be extending from `TrackBar` as it is not referencing the component that is currently on the screen.  Instead, pass a reference of `TrackBar` to the `TrackBarAction` so it perform actions directly on it.  I could be wrong, but there's not enough code to be sure

Comment: I sent a reference of 'TrackBar' to 'TrackBarAction' (updated the code), but I havent got the result yet

Comment: You now need to translate the x/y values to the `TrackBar`, in you `actionPerformed` method, you have no need for the `x`, `y`, `velX` and `velY` values, as these should be coming from, been set to the `TrackBar`.  You should also be calling `repaint` on the `TrackBar` instance.  The use of `static` variables is going to make your life very difficult and, for what you're using them for, I would avoid them and rely on the instance of the `TrackBar` to manage them

Comment: You also need to show us how you are adding the track bar to the main UI, please

Comment: I would not use static, yet I'm only using them since I'm calling Timer from another class and its the only way it lets me start it without creating an object...I'm going to give it a try with what I understand from what you said

Comment: I added the Main frame from where I call the `TrackBar` class

Comment: If you need to access `TrackBar` from another class, you should using an instance of the `TrackBar`, in particular, the instance that is on the screen.  If you have more then one `TrackBar`, you're screwed

Answer (score 2):

As MadProgrammer pointed out, the convoluted inheritance structure you have is unnecessary.

What is breaking your posted code is that your timer is manipulating the drawing coordinates of a second, offscreen TrackBar. Since your TrackBarAction is by inheritance also a TrackBar, the code compiles fine as the various animation variables all exist. But, they belong to the unrendered TrackBar rather than the original TrackBar instance that you are actually using.

```
    public class TrackBarAction implements ActionListener
{

private TrackBar tb;

public TrackBarAction( TrackBar tb )
{

    this.tb = tb;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
{
    System.out.println( "3" );

    // When it gets to the end, return to start point
    if ( tb.x == 1024 ) {
    tb.x = 0;
    tb.y = 0;
    }

    tb.x += tb.velX;
    tb.y += tb.velY;
    tb.repaint();
    System.out.println( "4" );
}

}
```

EDIT: this is what your updated TrackBarAction should look like. What you have conceptually wrong is the notion that the primitive instance variables of your version of TrackBarAction are passed by value and not by reference as objects are. So, you are manipulating the wrong variables in your version.

Comment: I understand what you said, I confused myself and have updated the code, the debug prints are still printing yet the Trackbar is not moving at all =/

Comment: You are passing the wrong instance of TrackBar. Note, in the call to your TrackBarAction constructor, you create an anonymous new instance of TrackBar. So, you end up updating the coordinates for this unused, unrendered TrackBar. You want to pass a reference to the one that ends up in your GUI. The quick fix for this is to remove the static keyword in front of the Timer variable and pass "this" to the TrackBarAction constructor.

Comment: ok, I got confused since I did not think I could make the call of `TrackBar` from `MainFrame` a static so I can access it, but Infact I can, and now I can take out the static variables from the `TrackBar` class. So it is working! I have Updated the code for reference! Thanks so much!

Comment: I dont know which to choose as answer since you both gave input to make the answer :p

Answer (score 1):

This `private static TrackBarAction tba = new TrackBarAction(new TrackBar());` and this

```
TrackBar tb = new TrackBar();
bg.add(tb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Are problems.  The reference that the `TrackBarAction` has is no longer the reference that is on the screen.

The use of static variables in this way is bad design and problematic...

```
public class TrackBar extends JPanel{

    private TrackBarAction tba;
    private int TIME = 8;

    private Timer t = new Timer(TIME, tba);
    private double x = 0, y = 0, velX = 0.5, velY = 0;

    public TrackBar() {
        tba =  = new TrackBarAction(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        System.out.println("1"); // debug

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        //g2d.drawRect((int)x, (int)y, 10, 800);

        Rectangle2D r2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 10.0, 800.0);  // x,x, w, h
        g2d.setPaint(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g2d.fill(r2d);
        g2d.draw(r2d);

        System.out.println("2"); // debug
    }
}
```

Then every class that needs to interact with the `TrackBar` should get the same instance (of the instance that they need to work with)

Comment: Yup! Thanks for the input, you and Creakazoid enlightened me and found the solution. Took out the static variables from `TrackBar`, made the object of `TrackBar` in `MainFrame` a static variable and started the timer from there, and it works! Thanks :)